# Why Can't I Create A Getter for a Private UIRefreshControl Property in CDTVC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uirefreshcontrol

I am able to create a getter for the public refresh control.

But when I try the same for the private refresh control it does not work.

e.g.

```
//MyClass.h 

@interface MyClass : CoreDataTableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIRefreshControl *myPublicRefreshControl; 
@end


// MyClass.m

@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIRefreshControl *myPrivateRefreshControl; 
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (UIRefreshControl*)myPublicRefreshControl{

 if(!_myPublicRefreshControl) {

       _myPublicRefreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
  }
      return _myPublicRefreshControl;
}
```

I am able to create a getter for the public refresh control.

But when I try the same for the private refresh control. i.e.

```
- (UIRefreshControl*)myPrivateRefreshControl{

 if(!_myPrivateRefreshControl) {

_myPrivateRefreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
 }
 return _myPrivateRefreshControl;
}

@end
```

Xcode is not able to to find the instance variable _myPrivateRefreshControl.

It gives the error

"Use of undeclared identifer '_myPrivateRefreshControl'"

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: In the .m file you have "@propery", missing the 't'. Is that a typo?

Comment: Using that code works fine for me...

Comment: Have you overridden the setter as well?  Xcode will give that error if you override both the getter and setter for a property.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. No I haven't. I'm aware of that one, thanks, have to @synthesize when do both.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I see which may be causing problems.  First, you misspelled `@property` as "@propery".  I suspect, however, this is just a type-o in your question as the compiler would have warned you about it in your actual code.

Second, it looks like both of your `@interface` declarations are creating unnamed Categories rather than classes.  This is probably causing the compiler to ignore/misinterpret your second declaration.  Try removing the `()` following your class declaration in the header.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, they were actually both typos. Problem still occurring.

Comment: In theory, your code looks correct to me.  Have you tried double-checking for other typos?  I find using cut-n-paste to copy the name around (particularly for long names) is helpful.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your time. I have included something I originaly omitted on purpose. MyClass is a SubClass of CoreDataTableViewController. https://gist.github.com/CloudNiner/8681866

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to make any difference unless there was some collision with another property in the superclass (which, it doesn't look like is the case).  Have you tried reproducing the problem with a brand new class which includes literally nothing else?  My guess is that it would work just fine, and that your problem stems from something you've omitted in your example.